# Javascript Sticky Note with 24 cookie and also a "never display again" option

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup, sticky

I found a script on Dynamic Drive I'd like to modify called sticky note. I'd like to change the sessions for each cookie to 7 days instead of 'per browser session" and also display a "Never Show Again" tick box or link so that the popup doesnt constantly annoy the readers of the site.

This is the link to the script: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/stickynote.htm

I found a thread where it shows how to create a cookie to display it every 24 hours instead, but I'd like it once every 7 days: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?29947-Sticky-Note-With-Cookie-Write-Read-Addition

How would I go about doing these two things? the 7 day cookie and the Never Display Again option?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the sample code, this is where the real work occurs:

```
var expireDate = new Date()
var expstring=expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+1) //1 day to expire
document.cookie="fadedin=yes; expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()
```

The above code creates a new date, and sets it to tomorrow and then includes it within a cookie as the expiration time. You can change the "1" to "7" to have it expire 7 days later.

For Never Show Again, you can set a cookie in the same format (but never to expire) and read that in the code that opens the popup.

I recommend looking up things like `document.cookie` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript to find out how they are structured, so you can go beyond just cutting-and-pasting others' code and fully understand it or if not, to know how to find out more.